Can we skip ElasticSearch's Analyzer for full-text retrieval through plugins
Can ElasticSearch's analyzer be skipped using plugins?
For example, in the search link, query analysis, recall, sorting, and other operations are usually performed. Why not directly use the query analysis results in the search link for recall and skip the query analysis process in Elasticsearch full-text retrieval.
I am learning ElasticSearch and hope to get some answers.It would be awesome if someone could explain me that :)
Thanks.
